# Java library for downloading a single file in multiple segments/chunks with multiple connections

Tags: java, http

As the title says, I'm looking for a library to do this in Java. Similar to [multipart-download package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multipart-download) in NodeJS.

I've been looking at a lot of HTTP clients but couldn't find any that supports this. It's crazy there is nothing like this in Java.

To be fair I already have a POC code that does this using low level Java code but I want to use a library to avoid polishing this code, making it prod ready and to maintain in the long run.

---

Similar questions found in stack overflow:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293204/download-single-file-with-multiple-connection-in-java
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243073/java-multiple-connection-downloading